# Posting an excel workbook modified through openpyxl using request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have an excel sheet that I wrote on memory and that I want to modify using openpyxl. Due to several circumstances I cannot use temporary files or anything of the sort. I am also writing the original sheet not using openpyxl, but xlsxwriter, for reasons that I do not wish to elaborate upon. The original sheet is saved in a bytes-like format, however, so I am wondering if I can do the same with the modified excel sheet and then upload it using requests.

This is the code I am using:

```
def UploadXLS(name, xlsx):
   wb = opx.load_workbook(io.BytesIO(xlsx))     
   wb.security = WorkbookProtection(workbookPassword = 'super-secret-password', lockStructure = True)
   wb.save(name)

   r = requests.post('my-url-here', 
                      files = wb)
return r.url
```

And this is the (predictable) error message I am getting:

```
a bytes-like object is required, not 'Workbook'
```

Any help or advice on the topic would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to open the file and add the file stream to the request, not the workbook object.

Comment: There is no reason not to use a temporary file because openpyxl uses them anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are attempting to pass the openpyxl `Workbook` object to the `post()` request. However, `post()` does not know how to handle a `Workbook`. But it **does** know how to handle any generic file stream. So the solution is to open the file and pass the stream to the request:

```
file = open(name, 'r')
r = requests.post('url', files=file)
```

Comment: Ok, I have a very dumb follow-up question but here it comes: isn't it technically already open? Or am I tripping over myself?

Comment: @NL Is what already open? The Excel file? Perhaps...your code doesn't include the details about the value or type of `xslx`. If this is a file stream from a Excel file on the file system, then there would be no need to wrap it in `io.BytesIO()`. Additionally, I don't think it would be reusable to pass into `post()` because it is already used by `load_workbook()`. There might be a way to ensure the stream is reset to the beginning, but it's much clearer to open your own file stream rather than reuse the one that is used to make changes to the excel file.